# Set gravity of a View Programmatically

Tags: java, android, view, gravity

Im working on a `View` over Android Source Code. I was wondering how can we setup multiple gravities, to a custom `View`

This is the XML

```
<com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.Clock
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        />
```

As you see, default gravity is center_vertical|left, so my Java code should be something like this

```
    View clock = mStatusBarView.findViewById(R.id.clock);

    if (clock != null) {
        SOMEHOW SET GRAVITY -> mCenterClock ? Gravity.CENTER : (Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT);
    }
```

setGravity method don't work on `View`. So is there an alternative of setting gravity without losing the width and height by default?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you really want gravity or do you want layout_gravity?

Comment: android:gravity="center_vertical|left", this is the attribute I wanna change. So I guess is just gravity? am I wrong?

Comment: no, I understand, now - but Agarwal is right: use the actual type, not View, since the actual type will likely respond to setGravity

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.Clock extends TextView just cast it to a TextView and set the gravity.

```
 TextView clock = (TextView) mStatusBarView.findViewById(R.id.clock);
 clock.setGravity(mCenterClock ? Gravity.CENTER : (Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT));
```

Ref: [Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/Clock.java)

Comment: Could you take a look here
https://github.com/AOKP/frameworks_base/blob/ics/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java

and here
https://github.com/AOKP/frameworks_base/blob/ics/packages/SystemUI/res/layout/status_bar.xml

Seems like is the best way. I think your way is not working because is a linearLayout.

Comment: I ended up by porting code from AOKP source, however your answer was the more accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried?

```
clock.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Edit:

Since you cannot use `setGravity` for a plain `View`, do something like this,

You can use a `RelativeLayout` and set a rule like this...

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, clock.getId());
```

Comment: Yes. setGravity method is not available for this View. So it wont compile

Comment: does Clock extend a certain type of viewgroup? Or just a generic view? It may make more sense to extend a viewgroup, such as LinearLayout.

Comment: I'll give it a try, however HandlerExploit solution seems also possible

Comment: Yes that is the best solution, my answer would have been the same if I knew that your Custom View extends TextView. +1 for his answer..

You can also do this if in future your View doesn't extend TextView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.Clock clock = (com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.Clock)mStatusBarView.findViewById(R.id.clock);

 clock.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

try the above code and remove  View clock = mStatusBarView.findViewById(R.id.clock);

Comment: Or just import `com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.Clock` to not clutter your codebase, if you prefer